# How do I concat to c++ path without mutating?

Tags: c++, filesystems, std

I thought I'd found the right function: `std::filesystem::path::concat` to do something like

```
auto b = path(C:a/b); 
const auto c = b.concat(/c);
```

`c` has the right value, but `b` is mutated (it ultimately equals `c`).

I want `b` to remain unaffected. According to the documentation, `concat` is equivalent to `operator+=`. However, there's no `operator+`.

I think is a weird design, because there's the similar `operator/=` and `operator/` where `/` means subdirectory instead of literal concat (like `+=`).

Can I do this non-mutating concat without something like `const auto c = std::filesystem::path(b.string() + "/c")`?

Comment: As an aside, you could always handle this with a free function: `template <typename T> std::filesystem::path concat_path(std::filesystem::path p, T && arg) { p += std::forward<T>(arg); return p; }`

Comment: @FredLarson I spoke about the difference in the question, `/` appends as a subdirectory but `+= (concat)` is a literal path concat

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi: Yes, I see that now. Sorry.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi The `p` argument is passed by-value (hence copied). So `auto a = concat_path(b, c);` is roughly the same as `auto a = b; a += c;`. (`b` is not mutated.)

Comment: @cdhowie I see, I thought about doing something like `temp = path.clone(); c = temp += "/c"` I guess your function wraps this up

Comment: or `c = b; c += "/c"`. Is this just a matter of an operator that was forgotten to be added?

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137433/why-do-boostfilesystempath-and-stdfilesystempath-lack-operator) and [this LWG defect](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2668).  Basically, `boost::filesystem::path` (on which the standard version is based) doesn't have an `operator+` and the committee doesn't want to add one because it would make the interface more complex.